# Could not resolve host: github.com while installing home-brew

Tags: git, github, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I am running high OS Sierra , I am installing homebrew for first time,
but I am getting this weird error and not able to resolve whats happening

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Error I got

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Could not resolve host: github.com
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force
```

I even created account on GitHub, used those credentials for `git config`

```
git config --global user.email "yourGitHub@email.com"
git config --global user.name "yourGitHubusername"
```

Comment: Maybe your web browser is using different DNS than your terminal, possibly via a proxy? Is github.com in your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: How to make chrome browser DNS same as Mac terminal DNS

Comment: Disable your proxy.

Comment: And how to add GitHub to /etc/hosts path

Comment: No, it's bad to have github in /etc/hosts. If you don't have it in that file, that's good.

Comment: I tried this one to disable proxy , git config --global --unset http.proxy

Comment: I meant disable proxy in Chrome.

Comment: @RobinGreen chrome proxy is already disabled

Comment: and I am doing this command from terminal , what this have to do with browser proxy settings

Comment: We know that you can create an account on GitHub, right? So I was checking if there was something different in the configuration that allowed Chrome to find GitHub even though git couldn't. Another possibility is the /etc/resolv.conf file contains a wrong DNS server. Or maybe you just have a flaky internet connection and if you retry it enough times, it will work.

Comment: Can you how us the output of `curl https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/` ? Are you using an application firewall such as Little Snitch or a proxy?